# ionic error while getting data from woocommerece api

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I am not able to spot what I am doing wrong. I have installed the woocommerce node package, and i have checked the rest api with the help postman app.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  WooCommerce: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.WooCommerce = WC({
        url: "http://localhost/wordpress",
        consumerKey: ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        consumerSecret: cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    });


   this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then((data)=>{
   console.log(data);
    }, (err)=>{
    console.log(err)

    })


  }
}
```

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: Thanks @Jodeveloper8 for looking I have added the screen shot kindly check it.

Comment: OK I see 
`consumerKey`  and `consumerSecret` should be in  rapped in quotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`this.WooCommerce = WC({
   url: "http://localhost/wordpress",
   consumerKey: ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
   consumerSecret: cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
});`

to 

`this.WooCommerce = WC({
   url: "http://localhost/wordpress",
   consumerKey: "ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   consumerSecret: "cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});`

Notice the quotes.

Comment: why do I get this error:Type 'typeof HomePage' has no properties in common with type 'Component'.

Comment: Change `HomePage: Component` to `HomePage: any`.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are learning from my course on Ionic and WooCommerce.